# SQL query - List number of items based on Qty

Tags: sql

I am using MS SQL 2008. I wonder if it is possible to produce a query that displays the results based on the Qty.  Please let me explain how I want it to look like.

Let's say, I have this table and a simple query to list the records:

```
Table = "Table1"
Product = varchar(100)
Qty = Int

Select Product, ProductDesc, Qty FROM Table1

Results:
Product     ProductDesc     Qty
ABC1        Test1           2
ABC2        Test2           3
```

Is there a way to query that based on the Qty column and listing the number of records like this result below:

```
**Wanted Results:**
Product     ProductDesc     Number
ABC1        Test1           1
ABC1        Test1           2
ABC2        Test2           1
ABC2        Test2           2
ABC2        Test2           3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use recursive query:

```
with p
as (
    select product,productDesc, 1 as number from products 
    union all 
    select products.product,products.productDesc, p.number+1 as number from products 
      inner join p on products.product = p.product
      where number<qty
   )
select * from p order by product
```

A simplified example: [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1e82e/3)

Comment: Thanks! when I tried to click the sample link fiddle, I got this error: Problem accessing /sqlfiddle/sqlfiddle/index.html. Reason: Not Found.  Any idea why?

Comment: But I access it normally

Comment: Maybe my PC has problem. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Not sure this is the right way but should work

```
with cte as
(
select 1 as num
union all
select num+1 from cte where num < 1000 -- max qty from your table
), comb as 
(
select Product,ProductDesc,num from
(select distinct Product,ProductDesc from Table1) t cross join cte c
)
select * from Table1 t
inner join comb c on t.Product = c.Product 
and t.ProductDesc = c.ProductDesc 
and c.qty <= t.num
```

For simplicity i have used `Recursive CTE` to generate number but it could be a problem with performance. Check [*here*](http://sqlperformance.com/2013/01/t-sql-queries/generate-a-set-1) for different methods to generate number without loop.